# When reading from dictionary I get 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__' error

Tags: python

In one python file I store values in a dictionary
eg:

```
 messageDict[ObservationRawDataId] = {'timestamp': TimeStamp, 'tanksystemid': TankSystemId,
                        'newDelivery': delivery,'oldDelivery':RawDeliveryLitres ,'grade' :ProductName,'sitecode':SiteCode}
 formMessageBody(messageDict)
```

In another python file I try to formulate a plain text messge from that dictionary;

```
def formMessageBody( messageDict) :
    try :
        print 'SiteCode', 'Date', 'Product', 'NewDelievry','OldDelivery'
        for tuple_a in messageDict.items():
            for dic_a in tuple_a:
                print tuple_a
                print dic_a['sitecode']
                print  dic_a['sitecode'], dic_a['timestamp'], dic_a['grade'],
                                                            dic_a['newDelivery'],dic_a['oldDelivery']
    except Exception as error:
        print format(error)
```

but I could not read value from the tuple.
tuple_a prints as;

```
(14118912, {'newDelivery': '8397.000', 'grade': u'Unleaded', 'timestamp': datetime.datetime(2019, 6, 23, 0, 0), 'tanksystemid': 5977, 'oldDelivery': 8397.0, 'sitecode': u'1156'})
```

When I try to retrieve;
dic_a['sitecode']
dic_a['timestamp']
I get;

```
'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

error.
What Im doing wrong here?

messageDict looks liek;

```
{14090233: {'newDelivery': '5009.000', 'grade': u'E10', 'timestamp': datetime.datetime(2019, 6, 21, 0, 0), 'tanksystemid': 5776, 'oldDelivery': 5009.0, 'sitecode': u'4169'}, 14129146: {'newDelivery': '17091.000', 'grade': u'Unleaded', 'timestamp': datetime.datetime(2019, 6, 24, 0, 0), 'tanksystemid': 8720, 'oldDelivery': 17091.0, 'sitecode': u'2328'}, 14118907: {'newDelivery': '13797.000', 'grade': u'Unleaded', 'timestamp': datetime.datetime(2019, 6, 23, 0, 0), 'tanksystemid': 5973, 'oldDelivery': 13797.0, 'sitecode': u'1151'}, 14145533: {'newDelivery': '8281.000', 'grade': u'PULP', 'timestamp': datetime.datetime(2019, 6, 24, 0, 0), 'tanksystemid': 5360, 'oldDelivery': 8281.0, 'sitecode': u'2212'}, 14129150: {'newDelivery': '7099.000', 'grade': u'Diesel', 'timestamp': datetime.datetime(2019, 6, 24, 0, 0), 'tanksystemid': 8724, 'oldDelivery': 7099.0, 'sitecode': u'2328'}, 14129565: {'newDelivery': '16619.100', 'grade': u'Unleaded', 'timestamp': datetime.datetime(2019, 6, 24, 0, 0), 'tanksystemid': 10012, 'oldDelivery': 16619.1, 'sitecode': u'4217'}}
```

Comment: how does `messageDict` look like?

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh added the sample dict

Comment: You go `for dic_a in tuple_a:` but the first element in the tuple is not a dict, but an integer (`14118912`) and an integer cannot be indexed with `'sitecode'`.

Comment: @Grismar tahnks got it. I have to use  if isinstance(dic_a,dict):

Comment: That works, but since I think your tuple here will always be some `int` followed by the `dict` you're interested in, you could also just look at `tuple_a[1]` instead of going `for dic_a in tuple_a`. There's other issues with your code, but one step at a time, I suppose.

Comment: You do not need `isinstance()` here. In `formMessageBody` do you want to do anything with the outer keys of `messageDict`, like the `14090233` in your example? If not, the answer by Tomothy32 should work for you.

Comment: BTW, you really should switch to Python 3. Python 2 reaches its official End Of Life at the start of next year.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you only want to iterate the values of the dictionary. If so, you can accomplish this by iterating through `messageDict.values()`. This also removes the need for the inner for loop:

```
for dic_a in messageDict.values():
    print dic_a['sitecode']
    print dic_a['sitecode'], dic_a['timestamp'], dic_a['grade'],
          dic_a['newDelivery'], dic_a['oldDelivery']
```

Answer (score 2):

Other people have already pointed out the problem, I'll just try to explain it a little more as to why it is happening the way it is happening.

Your `messageDict` is a dictionary with the `ObservationRawDataId` as key and another dict as value. When you call `messageDict.items()`, it returns a tuple `(ObservationRawDataId, {'timestamp': TimeStamp...`, so the first value in the tuple is `ObservationRawDataId` and not the `dic_a` as you are expecting it. If you want to iterate over the values, you can do it as @Tomothy32 suggested:

```
for dic_a in messageDict.values():
    print dic_a['sitecode']
    print dic_a['sitecode'], dic_a['timestamp'], dic_a['grade'],
          dic_a['newDelivery'], dic_a['oldDelivery']
```

Or if you want to use `ObservationRawDataId` somewhere in the loop too, you can use:

```
for rawDataId in messageDict.keys():
    dic_a = messageDict[rawDataId]
    print dic_a['sitecode']
    print dic_a['sitecode'], dic_a['timestamp'], dic_a['grade'],
          dic_a['newDelivery'], dic_a['oldDelivery']
```

Comment: For the second option,  `for rawDataId, dic_a in messageDict.items():` is probably a little nicer.

Answer (score 0):

When you iterate through the list returned by `messageDict.items()`, you get tuples of **key-value** pairs (in your case int-dict pairs). It seems like you are expecting only the values to be iterated through.

As you mentioned when you print the tuple, you get

> (14118912, {'newDelivery': '8397.000', 'grade': u'Unleaded', 'timestamp': datetime.datetime(2019, 6, 23, 0, 0), 'tanksystemid': 5977, 'oldDelivery': 8397.0, 'sitecode': u'1156'})

Note the first object in the tuple.
So through the first iteration of the inner loop, the variable `dic_a` stores `14118912` and calling `dic_a['sitecode']` is what causes an error as an int object of course does not support this (This must be the __getitem__ attribute error thrown).

What I think you wanted to do is call `messageDict.values()` which only returns a list of the values (in your case a list of dictionary objects) in the dictionary.